# What is cursor.setNotificationUri() used for?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-cursor

I did research on how to use `ContentProviders` and Loaders from [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo_contentprovider)

How I see it:
We have an `Activity` with `ListView`, `SimpleCursorAdapter` and `CursorLoader`. We also implement `ContentProvider`.

In an `Activity` we can call `getContentResolver().insert(URI, contentValues);` via a button click.

In our implementation of `ContentProvider`, at the end of `insert()` method, we call `getContentResolver().notifyChange(URI, null);` and our `CursorLoader` will receive message that it should reload data and update UI. Also if we use `FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER` in `SimpleCursorAdapter` it will also receive message and its method `onContentChanged()` will be called.

So our ListView will be updated if we insert, update or delete data.

`Activity.startManagingCursor(cursor);` is deprecated, `cursor.requery()` deprecated, so I do not see any practice sense from  `cursor.setNotificationUri()`.

I looked into `setNotificationUri()` method's source code and saw that it calls `mContentResolver.registerContentObserver(mNotifyUri, true, mSelfObserver)` inside the method. Also `CursorLoader` does the same. Finally cursor will receive message and the following method will be called inside Cursor:

```
protected void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    synchronized (mSelfObserverLock) {
        mContentObservable.dispatchChange(selfChange, null);
        // ...
    }
}
```

But I can not make sense of this.

So my question is: **why should we call `cursor.setNotificationUri()` in `query()` method of our `ContentProvider` implementation?**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you call `Cursor.setNotificationUri()`, Cursor will know what *ContentProvider Uri* it was created for.

`CursorLoader` registers its own `ForceLoadContentObserver` (which extends `ContentObserver`) with the `Context`'s `ContentResolver` for the URI you specified when calling `setNotificationUri`.

So once that `ContentResolver` knows that URI's content has been *changed* [ this happens when you call `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,  contentObserver);` inside `ContentProvider`'s `insert()`, `update()` and `delete()` methods ] it notifies all the observers including CursorLoader's `ForceLoadContentObserver`.

`ForceLoadContentObserver` then marks Loader's mContentChanged as true

Comment: Even through I am late to the party,
my questions is, is this possible even for another application which is using this URI to query our ContentProvider ?

Answer (score 15):

`CursorLoader` registers observer for the cursor, **not** to the URI.

Look into [CursorLoader's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/CursorLoader.java#53) below. Notice that `CursorLoader` registers `contentObserver` to the `cursor`.

```
/* Runs on a worker thread */
    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isLoadInBackgroundCanceled()) {
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }
            mCancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
        }
        try {
            Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(mUri, mProjection, mSelection,
                    mSelectionArgs, mSortOrder, mCancellationSignal);
            if (cursor != null) {
                try {
                    // Ensure the cursor window is filled.
                    cursor.getCount();
                    cursor.registerContentObserver(mObserver);
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    cursor.close();
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            return cursor;
        } finally {
            synchronized (this) {
                mCancellationSignal = null;
            }
        }
```

The `Cursor` needs to call method `setNotificationUri()` to register `mSelfObserver` to the `uri`.

```
//AbstractCursor.java
public void setNotificationUri(ContentResolver cr, Uri notifyUri, int userHandle) {
        synchronized (mSelfObserverLock) {
            mNotifyUri = notifyUri;
            mContentResolver = cr;
            if (mSelfObserver != null) {
                mContentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(mSelfObserver);
            }
            mSelfObserver = new SelfContentObserver(this);
            mContentResolver.registerContentObserver(mNotifyUri, true, mSelfObserver, userHandle); // register observer to the uri
            mSelfObserverRegistered = true;
        }
    }
```

Inside the `contentProvider`'s `insert`, `update`, `delete` methods, you need to call `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` to notify change to the `uri` observers.

So if you don't call `cursor#setNotificationUri()`, your `CursorLoader` will not receive notification if data underlying that `uri` changes.

Answer (score 0):

I use one URI for the cursor adaptor.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Uri uri = TemperatureContract.SensorEntry.buildSensorID0AddressUri(mDeviceAddress);
    args.putParcelable("URI", uri);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (args != null) {
        Uri mUri = args.getParcelable("URI");
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                mUri,
                null, // projection
                null, // selection
                null, // selectionArgs
                null); // sortOrder
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

On another class, I **use a different URI to change the database contents**. To have my view updated, I had to change the *default* implementation of the data provider's `update` method. The default implementation only notifies the same URI. I have to notify another URI.

I ended up by calling the `notifyChange()` twice on my data provider class, on the `update` method:

```
@Override
public int update(
        Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    int rowsUpdated;
    switch (match) {
        case ...:
            break;
        case SENSOR_BY_ID_AND_ADDRESS:
            String sensorId = TemperatureContract.SensorEntry.getSensorIdFromUri(uri);
            String sensorAddress = TemperatureContract.SensorEntry.getSensorAddressFromUri(uri);
            rowsUpdated = db.update(
                    TemperatureContract.SensorEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "sensorid = ? AND address = ?", new String[]{sensorId, sensorAddress});
            if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
                Uri otheruri = TemperatureContract.SensorEntry.buildSensorID0AddressUri(sensorAddress);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(otheruri, null);
            }
            break;
        case ...:
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }
    if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }
    return rowsUpdated;
```

I did the same for the `insert`and `delete` methods.