# Difference between cursor.setNotificationUri() and getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I am new to android can any one tell me what is the difference between `cursor.setNotificationUri()` and `getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null)` while implementing content provider.

I have seen that `cursor.setNotificationUri()` is used in `query()` method and while updating or inserting `getContentResolver().notifyChange()` is used.

I have little understanding that `getContentResolver().notifyChange()` notifies resolver that some data has been changed but what does `cursor.setNotificationUri()` do there ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is cursor.setNotificationUri() used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623714/what-is-cursor-setnotificationuri-used-for)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are used symbiotically. If you are implementing a `ContentProvider`, essentially when someone queries your provider, you produce a `Cursor` and call `setNotificationUri()` on it with some rational `Uri` (such as the `Uri` used to make the query). Later, if data served by your `ContentProvider` changes, e.g. after an insert/update/delete, you call `getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)` so that anyone who currently has a `Cursor` (because they queried earlier) gets notified that data has changed and they should re-query. If they are using a `CursorLoader`, the re-query happens automatically.

Comment: I noticed one thing, if you don't use `setNotificationUri()` in `query()` method and `notifyChange()` in update/delete/insert methods, your Content Provider will still work the same.